# Issue with pagination columns and rows in PHP

Tags: php, pagination, rows

I'd like to display 20 records in 5 columns with 4 rows and have the "Next"/"Previous" button at the bottom.

For some reason, `$rowsperpage = 5` winds up in 1 row and 5 columns. If I increase the number, it just adds another column.

The actual pagination works fine but the columns and rows aren't cooperating.

Any idea how I can achieve the desired effect?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
// find out how many rows are in the table 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];

// number of rows to show per page

$rowsperpage = 5;
// find out total pages
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

// get the current page or set a default
if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
    // cast var as int
    $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
    // default page num
    $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
    // set current page to last page
    $currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1) {
    // set current page to first page
    $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// the offset of the list, based on current page 
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

// get the info from the db 
$sql = "SELECT id, name, picture, phone, address1 FROM users LIMIT $offset,             $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

// while there are rows to be fetched...
echo "<table  style='width: 800px; height: 250px'>";

echo "<tr style='width: 800px;'>";

while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // echo data
    echo "<td align='center' style='width: 800px; height: 250px'>" . $list        ['name'] . "<br /><a href='http://www.snarrf.com/onsale/detail.php?id=" . $list    ['id'] . "'><img src='http://www.snarrf.com/onsale/nooks/" . $list['picture'] . "'     height='100' width='100'  border='0' /></a><br />" . $list['address1'] ."</td>" ;

} // end while
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
/****** build the pagination links ******/
echo "<table align='center' >";
echo "<tr >";
echo "<td align='center' valign='top'><img src='images/sn1.gif'><br></td>";
// range of num links to show
$range = 3;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
    // show << link to go back to page 1
    //echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
    // get previous page num
    $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
    // show < link to go back to 1 page
    //echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
    // if it's a valid page number...
    if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
        // if we're on current page...
        if ($x == $currentpage) {
            // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
            echo "<td align='center'> <img src='images/sn2.gif' border='0'><br>$x </td>";
            // if not current page...
        } else {
            // make it a link
            echo " <td align='center' valign='top'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?        currentpage=$x'><img src='images/sn2.gif' border='0'><br>$x</a> </td>";



        } // end else
    } // end if 
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links 
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
    // get next page
    $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page 
    //echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> ";
    // echo forward link for lastpage
    //echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
} // end if






echo "<td valign='top'><img src='images/sn3.gif'><br></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";



echo "<table align='center' width='100' >";
echo "<tr width='100' >";
echo "<td >";
// range of num links to show
$range = 3;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
    // show << link to go back to page 1
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
    // get previous page num
    $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
    // show < link to go back to 1 page
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
    // if it's a valid page number...
    if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
        // if we're on current page...
        if ($x == $currentpage) {
            // 'highlight' it but don't make a link

            // if not current page...

        } else {

            // make it a link

        } // end else
    } // end if 
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links 
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
    // get next page
    $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page 
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> ";
    // echo forward link for lastpage
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
} // end if


echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";





/****** end build pagination links ******/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe replacing

```
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<td align='center' style='width: 800px; height: 250px'>" . $list          ['name'] . "<br /><a href='http://www.snarrf.com/onsale/detail.php?id=" . $list    ['id'] . "'><img src='http://www.snarrf.com/onsale/nooks/" . $list['picture'] . "'     height='100' width='100'  border='0' /></a><br />" . $list['address1'] ."</td>" ;
}
```

with

```
$rows_counter = 0;
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<td align='center' style='height: 250px'>" . $list['name'] . "<br /><a href='http://www.snarrf.com/onsale/detail.php?id=" . $list['id'] . "'><img src='http://www.snarrf.com/onsale/nooks/" . $list['picture'] . "'     height='100' width='100'  border='0' /></a><br />" . $list['address1'] ."</td>" ;
    if (!(++$rows_counter % 5) and $rowsperpage != $rows_counter)
        echo "</tr><tr>";
}
```

Should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome thanks - I had to tinker with the numbersa a bit but i got it

Comment: Just an fyi...
    $rows_counter = 20; 
wound up having to be the same value as
    $rowsperpage = 20;
in my case 20 (representing the number of total records I want)
and 
    if (!(++$rows_counter % 5)
should reflect the number of rows desired

thus 20 records in 5 rows yielding 4 columns = success!
thank for the help!!!

Comment: Ranty - How can I contact you directly? - I'd like to speak if possible. You maybe interested in a project i'm working on.

Comment: Feel free to mail me: skylight@list.ru